# How to implement linear regression using Least Mean Square algorithm

Tags: python, linear-regression, least-squares, pattern-recognition

I have a data set and I read it with pandas.
I want to predict a specific column of my data using the least mean square algorithm and then apply k-fold validation.
I am having trouble finding a way to apply the least mean square...there are no libraries and no examples of implementations.
Do you know what I should do ?

Comment: Have you looked into `sklearn` module?

Comment: yes, but from what I saw sklearn does linear regression with least square algorithm

Comment: Could you share the data? The LMS is suited for Online configuration, is that your intention?